# Tags [httpd] and [apache]: synonym candidates?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) seems to have a sligthtly bigger usage preference over [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd), most questions are tagged with both. By the way, I'd prefer [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) to be synonym to [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd), not the opposite.

#### EDIT:

My point is that Apache is more that just the http server sub-project; [apache-httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd) would be a better tag. Yet, using httpd for lighttpd or other web-servers, for historical reasons, would just be confusing, as lighttpd executable daemon is *not* even called httpd. Would you tolerate the httpd tag for IIs on ServerFault?

Comment: As per derobert's answer we should really get rid of `httpd` completely (as synonymous with `webserver`, which is less ambiguous) and then give various web server's their own tag.  This way, the `apache` tag can be also be used to cover the scope of the the project, and `webserver` added for specificity where appropriate.

Comment: Based on the answers below, I've gone through and re-tagged all of the [httpd]-tagged questions with either [apache-httpd] or, if generically-appropriate, [webserver]. Should we enforce the separation by blacklisting [httpd]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apache isn't the only httpd, and looking through that tag I indeed saw another httpd (lighttpd) on the first page...

Seems like maybe we should just get rid of [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd) entirely.

Questions about Apache get [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache); ones about lighttpd would get [lighttpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighttpd); etc.

If we want a generic tag, [webserver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webserver) would be much clearer, already exists, and is more popular.

Comment: +1 For recommending we split `httpd` up.  Although I presume apache is the only thing to use this as an in-path executable name, Wikipedia actually [lists 10 different servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Httpd) as possibilities.

Comment: apache is not the only httpd, but also, it is not only httpd, a lot more. editing my answer

Comment: @guido if you want to additionally retag almost all of the Apache HTTP Server questions [tag:apache-httpd], that seems like it should be a different question...

Comment: @derobert yep we can discuss here then we can close and make a new one eventually, thats why I included the question mark in the question title in the first instance :). By the way, i like the webserver tag proposition, but that leaves open the issue of httpd / apache tags. Are you proposing of making httpd a synonym for webserver, then having people to specify the implementation in another tag like apache-httpd (or just apache), lighttpd and so on?

Comment: @guido I propose we get rid of the httpd tag.

Comment: +1. BURNIATE IT!

Comment: Agree w/ you except that we should probably use apache-http or apache-httpd instead and use apache for apache software & foundation related Q's.

Answer (score 4):

Keep an open mind. Just because you know of only one type of HTTP server doesn't mean it's the only one. Take a look at all the HTTP servers available in this list via Wikipedia:

- [Comparison of web server software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software)

There are more than this and often servers just as Jetty, JBOSS, Tomcat, and many others can be dual purposed to serve static content as a HTTP server as well as serve as an application server.

#### List via wikipedia

[image: ss #1]

#### EDIT #1

With your edit I think your point is that Apache (the tag) could be associated with both the HTTPD server and the overarching project + the Apache Software Foundation.

I think part of the confusion is that most people associate the [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) with the HTTP web server sub-project vs. anything else. For example I think most people would be surprised that Tomcat (another subject) is in fact called Apache Tomcat.

I think part of the confusion stems from Ubuntu (assuming Debian does the same) packages the HTTP server with an executable called `apache2`.

#### What to do?

I think I would be inclined to reorganize the tags so that [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) is used as a tag for Apache related items (software, licensing, foundation), while [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd) and a synonym tag [apache-httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd) were used for actual HTTP server related items.

I dislike making [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) a synonym for [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd) since it can span multiple pieces of software.

Comment: we could discuss if we can consider apache the original http daemon (from the NCSA ashes), i do, however this is not the point; the point here is exaclty the fact that today the term apache by itself means the foundation, and using it for the subproject (httpd) is not precise.

Comment: @guido - see edits

Comment: I'm with you on everything but synonyming the httpd tag - IMHO, it's too ambiguous. I think we should blacklist it instead, as @derobert suggested, but we could add a note in the tag wiki that the asker probably meant apache-httpd.

Comment: Have you gone through [tag:apache] to see how many questions are about Apache software other than the web server?

Comment: @Gilles Well, first page includes an Apache Tomcat question. So there are some.

Answer (score 3):

Given the observations made by derobert and slm, we should use the tags

- [apache-httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd) for questions about the web server of the Apache project;
- other tags (e.g. [lighttpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighttpd)) for questions about a specific non-Apache web server;
- [webserver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webserver) for questions about web servers in general.

Since [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) is overwhelmingly used to mean “Apache web server”, we should make this a synonym to a more clearly specific tag: [apache-httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd). Since [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd) is a natural tag but a bit of a hodgepodge, we should make this a synonym of the more general tag [webserver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webserver) (if we don't make it a synonym, either it'll end up recreated or people will misuse [apache-httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd) obtained through completion).

We need to get rid of the tags [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) and [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd). Most of the 388 [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) questions are about Apache httpd, so we should track down the ones that aren't, then synonymize [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) to [apache-httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd).

There are 28 [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd) questions but only [13 that aren't also tagged apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd+-apache). So the easiest course of action is to retag these 13 tags, then get rid of [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd) and re-create it as a synonym of [webserver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webserver).

Here's the course of action:

1. (Community) Retag all 13 [[httpd] -[apache]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd+-apache) questions appropriately.
2. (Community) Go through [[apache] -[httpd]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache+-httpd) questions and retag the ones that aren't about the Apache web server.
3. (Moderator) Merge [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache) and [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd) into [apache-httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd), then remove the [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd) synonym and make [httpd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/httpd) a synonym of [webserver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webserver).

Comment: Although this dodges the OP's concern that "apache is more than just an httpd", so we need a general `apache` tag, I think that concern is really a non-issue; questions about "apache tomcat", etc. are fine with just `tomcat`.  Also, questions about most of the apache software projects (ant, commons, etc.) don't belong here anyway. So ditching `apache` in favour of `apache-httpd` sounds good to me.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' Are there questions about Apache in general, as opposed to a specific Apache software? We could create a tag like [tag:apache-project] if it's warranted.

Comment: I'm guessing there actually aren't, but maybe it's worth noting in case we (meaning: whoever) run across such a case when doing the re-tagging. `apache-project` would be better than just `apache`.